# How to input password when evaluate code block in Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have a shell code block in Org file. And there's "sudo" command in it. So I should be asked to  key in password. But when I evaluate it, it just return error for "sudo" command. Is it there's any way to make the evaluation kind of interactive?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there is, by adding appropriate [header arguments](http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-block-specific-header-arguments.html#Code-block-specific-header-arguments) to the `#+BEGIN_SRC` line:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo::
apt-get update
#+END_SRC
```

**Source**: [Running a sudo in a #+begin_src sh fails to get tty and askpass](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg00354.html) on the emacs-orgmode mailing list.

**Explanation**: The [`:dir`](http://orgmode.org/manual/dir.html#dir) argument

> specifies the default directory during code block execution. If it is absent, then the directory associated with the current buffer is used.

By passing `/sudo::` as a value to `:dir` we are making use of [TRAMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) syntax for accessing files or directories with superuser privileges. Note that in the example above we are not specifying a directory to use after `::`. In this case, `/root` will be used as a default. So essentially, what we are saying to [Org Babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) is "Access `/root` as root and use that location as the default directory when executing this code".

You can specify a different directory to use by changing `/sudo::` to

```
/sudo::/path/to/dir
```

---

**EDIT**

If you need some commands in the code block to run *without* superuser privileges, you can do so by putting

```
sudo -u <username>
```

in front of them (replacing `<username>` with the user name of a regular user). For illustration purposes, let's say your user name is `enchanter`, and you want any commands in your code block that don't require superuser privileges to be run as your own user. In this case, you would have to prefix each of these commands with

```
sudo -u enchanter
```

You can check that this works using `whoami` (which prints the name of the user that is currently "active"). Add

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo::
whoami
sudo -u enchanter whoami
whoami
#+END_SRC
```

to your `org-mode` file and evaluate it. The output will be:

```
#+RESULTS:
| root       |
| enchanter  |
| root       |
```

---

**Credits**

- [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425990) on AskUbuntu
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/93387/120085) on SuperUser

I am sure there are other posts on StackExchange/The Internet addressing the issue of running commands as a different user, but I stopped looking after I had found these...

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I think that will make all the command in the block run as sudo. But I only expect some of them run as SUDO. I got another ugly solution for now is use `echo "<password>" | sudo -S <command>`. I have to put my password in the org file which I don't really like it.

Comment: @enchanter There is a solution for that as well. I've edited my answer to include it. (And yes, storing passwords in plain text is a Bad Idea.

Comment: That's great. it is really opened my mind and try to solve the problem in different way.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @itsjeyd is good when you have most commands to run as SUDO.

But when you only have a small portion commands to run as SUDO, you have to code a lot of `sudo -u <username>` and you have to pass user name as variable if you want that block can be run by users.

For that case, I have a solution to use `echo <password> | sudo -S <your command>`

Here is the example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var PASSWORD=(read-passwd "Sudo Password: ")
   # some normal commands here and there

   # run sudo
   echo ${PASSWORD} | sudo -S <your command>

   # more normal commands
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: IMHO this is really bad idea. In this way you are displaying your `root` password in process list and any user/app on your computer can get it.

Comment: which makes zero issues for the few seconds on a single user machine.